Simple way to edit pdf page numbers
Every now and then I encounter a pdf file whose page numbers don't match the ones in the text. For example, it might be a book whose introduction is on pages i, ii, etc., so that "page 1" of the book is on page 12 of the pdf, for example.
If I'm lucky, a pdf will be set up with "logical page numbers", so that when I view it in Preview on my Mac, the pages will be labelled correctly, starting with i, ii, .... But often the pdf is not set up that way, and in that case I always have to scroll back and forth looking for the right page.
So I would like a way to edit the "logical page numbers" of a pdf, so that that "page 1" corresponds to what the text refers to as page 1.
My main criterion is that the software to do this be free and not trying to sell me something, and that the process be straightforward.
If I google this question I mostly get instructions to turn on "logical page numbers" in Preview. In my case this is already turned on - I'm asking for software that can edit the pdf such that this option will work correctly.

You can use the functions in section 11.5 of the cpdf (disclaimer, I wrote it) manual. Free for non-commercial use, if that meets your requirements:
https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf
